# Sort "Events Popular In Your Network" by date

Tags: facebook, facebook-events

In facebook, I like the Events Popular In Your Network page, but I want to see it in date order.

Possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, As of now its not possible. There is no way to sort *Events Popular In Your Network* by date.